# Write a maximum as integral of indicator function (clarification)

Tags: integration, random-variables

It is known that a random variable $X$ can be written in terms of positive and negative parts $X=X^+-X^-$.
Also, $X^+=\max(0,X)=\int_0^\infty I(X>x)dx$. I don't know how to show it.

Say that $a\in\mathbb{R}$. I can see that $\max(0,a)=aI(a>0)$, and that $a=\int_0^adx$. It indicates me that $\max(0,a)=\int_0^{aI(a>0)}dx$, but I can't relate this with $\max(0,a)=\int_0^\infty I(a>x)dx$.

Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, a real number $x\ge 0$ can be written as $\int_0^x 1\,dz$. Thus,
$$
X\vee 0=\int_0^{\infty} 1\{X\vee 0>z\}\,dz=\int_0^{\infty} 1\{X>z\}\,dz.
$$